# MVC 3 razor - maintain checkbox values between page requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, checkbox

I have a page with checkboxes which are used to filter a webgrid.

To give my question some context by unchecking a checkbox the data will be filtered to show fewer results in my webgrid by using ajax request. But once I click on the numbers below the webgrid to cycle through the next set of records in the grid I lose the current state of my checkboxes. This is because I am calling my ActionResult method again which is loading the page again.

So how do I maintain those checkbox values between page loads?

**This is my view**

```
@model IEnumerable<UserManager.Models.vw_UserManager_Model>


@*@model UserManager.Models.vw_UserManager_Model
*@
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "User Manager Dashboard";
}

    @Html.ActionLink("Create New User", "CreateUser")


<div class="webgrid-filter">
    <b>@Html.Label("Select a filter: ")</b>
    <br />
    @Html.Label("Toggle ALF Intelligence users:")
    <input name="User logged in" type="checkbox"  onclick="filterGrid('@Url.Action("Index", "UserManager")')" id="chkFilterAlfIntell" checked="checked" />
     @Html.Label("Toggle ALF Connect users:")
    <input name="User logged in" type="checkbox"  onclick="filterGrid('@Url.Action("Index", "UserManager")')" id="chkFilterAlfConn" checked="checked"/>
     @Html.Label("Toggle BRAD users:")
    <input name="User logged in" type="checkbox"  onclick="filterGrid('@Url.Action("Index", "UserManager")')" id="chkFilterBrad" checked="checked"/>
</div>

<div id="webgrid-wrapper">
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Partial/_WebGridUserManager.cshtml", Model)
    </div>
<br />


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        // Disable checkboxs where a user is not active.
        $(".webgrid-wrapper input:not(:checked)").attr("disabled", "disabled");

        // Style tables.
        function jQueryUIStyling() {
            $('input:button, input:submit').button();

            $('.webgrid-wrapper').addClass('ui-grid ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all');
            $('.webgrid-title').addClass('ui-grid-header ui-widget-header ui-corner-top');
            jQueryTableStyling();
        } // end of jQueryUIStyling

        function jQueryTableStyling() {
            $('.webgrid').addClass('ui-grid-content ui-widget-content');
            $('.webgrid-header').addClass('ui-state-default');
            $('.webgrid-footer').addClass('ui-grid-footer ui-widget-header ui-corner-bottom ui-helper-clearfix');
        } // end of jQueryTableStyling
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function filterGrid(url) {
        var filters = getFilterVals();
//        console.log(filters);

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            dataType: "html",
            data: "alfConnect=" + filters.alfConnect + "&" + "alfIntelligence=" + filters.alfIntelligence + "&" + "brad=" + filters.brad,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#webgrid-wrapper').empty().html(data);
//                $('#webgrid-wrapper').html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    function getFilterVals() {
        filters = new Object();
        if ($('.webgrid-filter #chkFilterAlfIntell').is(':checked')) {
            filters.alfIntelligence = 1;
        }
        else {
            filters.alfIntelligence = 0;
        }

        if ($('.webgrid-filter #chkFilterAlfConn').is(':checked')) {
            filters.alfConnect = 1;
        }
        else {
            filters.alfConnect = 0;
        }

        if ($('.webgrid-filter #chkFilterBrad').is(':checked')) {
            filters.brad = 1;
        }
        else {
            filters.brad = 0;
        }
        return filters;

    }

    function logUserOff(url) {
        var answer = confirm('Are you sure you want to save this data?')
        if (answer) {
//            alert(url + ": " + value);

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST"
//                data: value
            }).done(function () {
                $(this).addClass("done");
            });


            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    };
</script>
```

In div class webgrid filter you can see the checkboxes which I want to maintain the values of.

**My actionResult for this view**

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            try
            {
                var model = new UserManagerTestEntities().vw_UserManager_Model;
                //var model = new UserManager.Models.vw_UserManager_Model();
                return View(model.ToList());

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return View(ViewBag);
            }

        }
```

[image]

Does anyone have suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing action on your controller, maybe you could: as click action on checkbox call javascript function which at the end would make ajax call.

Comment: Do you have an example because I can't see how that would help?

Comment: Sorry for late response.  
Which action is taken on paging?  
The most probably you are passing page number only, you need to add additional parameter combined from checkbox values.  
On top of that in your Index method you can use the same method as for paging. Do not forget to make page number variable nullable.